# Read concatenated json objects in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading some json files in Spark which are getting dumped by firehose on S3. Unfortunately, the files are not separated by any delimiter. It looks like this:

```
[{"name": "abc", "age": 18},{"name": "pqr", "age": 19}][{"name": "xyz", "age": 20}]
```

It's a list of lists of json objects. There is no delimiter in between two lists and hence spark is not able to parse it. It just returns the json objects of first list. 
Using this code:

```
val df = spark.read.json(path)
```

It returns

```
-------------------------------
name     |  age
------------------------------- 
abc      |  18
-------------------------------
pqr      |  19
-------------------------------
```

Although, if I manually update the file to have lists on separate line, it works fine. It can read all json objects. But, that's something manual. How can I achieve the same in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

The JsonReader is not able to do this, but you can read the file as text, split the lines at the appropriate locations an then use the `from_json` function defined in [org.apache.spark.sql.functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)